# Logfile won't apear in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm very new to logstash and elasticsearch, I am trying to stash my first log to logstash in a way that I can (correct me if it is not the purpose) search it using elasticsearch....

I have a log that looks like this basically:

```
2016-12-18 10:16:55,404 - INFO - flowManager.py - loading metadata xml
```

So, I have created a config file test.conf that looks like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/usr/tmp/logs/mylog.log"
    type => "test-type"
    id => "NEWTRY"
 }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{SECOND:second} - %{LOGLEVEL:level} - %{WORD:scriptName}.%{WORD:scriptEND} - " }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts =>  ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "ecommerce"
    codec => line { format => "%{year}-%{month}-%{day} %{hour}:%{minute}:%{second} - %{level} - %{scriptName}.%{scriptEND} - \"%{message}\"" }
  }
}
```

And then : `./bin/logstash -f test.conf`

I do not see the log in elastic search when I go to: `http://localhost:9200/ecommerce` OR to `http://localhost:9200/ecommerce/test-type/NEWTRY`

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.... :\

Thanks,
Heather

Comment: try `http://localhost:9200/ecommerce/_search`

Comment: I get `{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}`.. I don't know if it's relevant but I added ecommerce index in kibana

Comment: Then your logs are not delivered to elasticsearch. See logstash's logs.

Comment: All it says (I'm looking in logstash-plain.log) is that it run health check and then that the connection has restored to ES instance... No errors...:/

Comment: add key `--log.level DEBUG` to cmd line args

Comment: I'm sorry I do have an error I did not noticed apperantly - `Failed to install template. {:message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://localhost:9600][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"` .. I will edit my question then cause I could not find a solution for that either... :/

Comment: Why port is 9600?

Comment: When I get the successfully started message it shows `{:port=>9600}` no matters what my host is so I tried to change it in case it has something to do with it... And therefore the ERROR was................. So I'm back to square one I run it again and there are no errors for sure checked 3 times...

Comment: I'm so sorry for the confusion I'm just trying really anything...

Comment: it should be port 9200

Comment: I guess that you config is not correct. I am not able to test it right now. Try to follow steps from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html

Comment: Port 9600 is for the Logstash monitoring API. As @user3775217 said it should be port 9200, what do you get now in the logs if you try that?

Comment: Config test result - `Config Validation Result: OK. Exiting Logstash`

Comment: I see some fatal errors regarding the patters like - `Adding pattern {"BACULA_LOG_MAXSTART"=>"Fatal error: Job canceled because max start delay time exceeded."}` but I used the grok debugger and it seems okay....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution eventually-

I added both `sincedb_path=>"/dev/null"` (which from what I understood is for testing enviorment only) and `start_position => "beginning"` to the output file plugin and the file appeared both in elastic and in kibana

Thanks anyway for responding and trying to help!